# Is thriple,a couple with 3 persons, a recognized word or a rarely used slang word?

Tags: slang

I cannot find "Thriple" in Cambridge or Oxford dictionary. I do not know if it is really used or not.

Comment: Why are you asking? Did you see it somewhere? Or did you just wonder that would be a reasonable way to say it?

Comment: It's in the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thriple).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be a commonly recognized word, outside of some informal or slang use.

Just thinking about it intuitively, however, my first thought was that if I were coining a new word based on *couple*, I would make it *thr-**ouple***. In other words, *throuple*, not *thriple*.

As a matter of fact, a Google search on *throuple* turned up [208,000 hits](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&ei=MV9wXJn5CYaLjwTbiLs4&q=%22throuple%22&oq=%22throuple%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.254890.258191..258405...5.0..0.146.1845.3j13......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i71j0i131j0i67j0i10.rD8XvWtldWs), whereas *thriple* produced [52,200 hits](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&ei=5GBwXOiHCIfGjgSXt7LIAg&q=%22thripple%22&oq=%22thripple%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i10l10.44823.46363..46692...0.0..0.149.1133.2j8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i7i10i30.4w1UT0Dji54). And unlike *throuple*, which had a relationship sense on all first-page hits for me, the first-page hits for *thriple* included some non-relationship senses.

Some references to *throuple* include:

- BBC News: ["What it's like to be in a 'throuple' relationship."](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/education-46267148/what-it-s-like-to-be-in-a-throuple-relationship)
- Cosmopolitan: ["This is what it's like to be in a three-way relationship."](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/uk/love-sex/relationships/a23280043/three-way-relationship/)
- Pride: ["15 Questions About Throuple Relationships by Derrick Barry Herself."](https://www.pride.com/gay/2016/12/23/15-questions-about-throuple-relationships-answered-derrick-barry-herself)
- After Ellen: ["Are Throuples The Relationship Of The Future?"](https://www.afterellen.com/columns/529399-throuples-relationship-future)

The Urban Dictionary offers definitions for both [*thriple*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thripple) and [*throuple*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Throuple) as a relationship with three people.

---

Neither *thriple* nor *throuple* is a word recognized by any main dictionary. While I might argue that *throuple* sounds more like *couple* and, therefore, would likely be more easily understood, I wouldn't suggest using either unless you knew you would be understood by your audience.